# How do I set up a Tomcat configuration for multiple Oracle databases with persistent connections?

Tags: oracle, tomcat

I have 3 separate LINUX servers each containing an Oracle database with one standalone Tomcat web server running on a fourth LINUX server.
Data from different sources on different networks is being written into each OracleDB.

What is the best practice or method to configure Tomcat for connectivity to each of these databases?
A persistant connection to all three is needed to initiate SQL queries and joins between each database as needed using from jstl / beans and jsp.

I saw some configuration examples using WEB-INF/web.xml and server.xml but didn’t see anything specifically addressing multiple database connections configured simular to this setup.

If someone has an example of a Tomcat configuration that addresses this type of connectivity or if there are article examples or pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: If everything else fails read the manual: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html Just configure one JNDI connection for each database.

Answer (score -1):

There are two solutions for your case:

1. Check this [LINK](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/configuring-an-oracle-datasource-in-apache-tomcat-339739363.html)
2. You can write different DB classes to send different connection request by using the following code:

   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.DriverManager;

   public class DBConnection{

   ```
   public static Connection getOracleConnection() throws Exception {
   String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
   String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@ServerIP:1521:XE";//You can add your server IP here 
   String username = "username";
   String password = "password";

   Class.forName(driver); 
   Connection cnn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
   return cnn;
   ```

   }
   }

Cheers!!

Comment: Hi Ghayel - thanks for the prompt response on this - this was very helpful ,  - Cheers!!!